# Unable To Add Gesture on Dynamically Added UILabel

Tags: ios, swift3, uilabel, uigesturerecognizer, xcode8

I am trying to add gesture  on a dynamically created label but its not working this the code but its not working. 
what am i doing wrong ?

```
let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 21))
label.center = CGPoint(x: 160, y: 285)
label.textAlignment = .center
label.text = field.text
label.isZoomEnabled = true;
label.minFontSize = 10;
label.maxFontSize = 80;
label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true;
label.setNeedsLayout()
label.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
let panRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:Selector(("handlePan:")))
let rotateRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:Selector(("handleRotate:")))
panRecognizer.delegate = self
rotateRecognizer.delegate = self
label.addGestureRecognizer(panRecognizer)
label.addGestureRecognizer(rotateRecognizer)
self.view.addSubview(label);
self.imagePicked.addSubview(label)
```

---

```
@IBAction func handlePan(recognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let translation = recognizer.translation(in: self.view)
    if let view = recognizer.view {
        view.center = CGPoint(x:view.center.x + translation.x,
                              y:view.center.y + translation.y)
    }
    recognizer.setTranslation(CGPoint(x:0,y:0), in: self.view)
}

@IBAction func handleRotate(recognizer : UIRotationGestureRecognizer) {
    if let view = recognizer.view {
        view.transform = view.transform.rotated(by: recognizer.rotation)
        recognizer.rotation = 0
    }
}
```

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating `UITapGestureRecognizer` but the methods were taking `UIPanGestureRecognizer` and `UIRotationGestureRecognizer`. Also changed the `selector` so the methods are called properly and changed `IBActions` to methods.

Replace your code with this and it will work fine,

```
let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 21))
    label.center = CGPoint(x: 160, y: 285)
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.text = field.text
    label.isZoomEnabled = true;
    label.minFontSize = 10;
    label.maxFontSize = 80;
    label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true;
    label.setNeedsLayout()
    label.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    let panRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:#selector(self.handlePan))
    let rotateRecognizer = UIRotationGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:#selector(self.handleRotate))
    panRecognizer.delegate = self
    rotateRecognizer.delegate = self
    label.addGestureRecognizer(panRecognizer)
    label.addGestureRecognizer(rotateRecognizer)
    self.view.addSubview(label);
    self.imagePicked.addSubview(label)
```

---

```
func handlePan(recognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let translation = recognizer.translation(in: self.view)
    if let view = recognizer.view {
        view.center = CGPoint(x:view.center.x + translation.x,
                              y:view.center.y + translation.y)
    }
    recognizer.setTranslation(CGPoint(x:0,y:0), in: self.view)
}

func handleRotate(recognizer : UIRotationGestureRecognizer) {
    if let view = recognizer.view {
        view.transform = view.transform.rotated(by: recognizer.rotation)
        recognizer.rotation = 0
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked because when you were creating UITapGestureRecognizer but the methods were taking UIPanGestureRecognizer and UIRotationGestureRecognizer. Also I changed the selector so the methods are called properly and changed IBActions to methods.

Answer (score 0):

It's the problem of `UIlabel's` superView.

I assume the `imagePicked` is an instance of `UIImageView`, and  the default value of `UIImageView's` `isUserInteractionEnabled` is flase.

So the `imagePicked` and all of it's subviews cannot receive touch events.

To fix this problem, enbale the `isUserInteractionEnabled` property of UIImageView:

```
self.imagePicked.isUserInteractionEnabled = true;
```